# How to optimally query many rows by id?

Tags: postgresql, sql-optimization, postgresql-performance

In my project, I often need to query many rows by their ids. I do queries like:

```
select * from mytable where id in (...)
```

The problem is, these queries are too slow for me. My table has around 3M rows, and when I ask for 150 ids like this, it takes around 3.5 seconds.

Running `explain` shows that this actually goes through the entire table:

```
Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..762403.70 rows=150 width=794)
   Filter: (id = ANY ('{...}'::bigint[]))
```

How do I change this?

Comment: do you have an index defined on the id column?

Comment: The `id` column is my primary key, and Postgres [automatically creates indices for primary key columns](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4C6BA0F6020000250003481C@gw.wicourts.gov).

**EDIT:** Oh, you got me! I was sure that the column was the primary key. Turns out it wasn't...

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be simple. As @marcosh suggested, the `id` column wasn't an index. So I did:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

...and it's much much faster now. Here's what `explain` says now:

```
Index Scan using mytable_pkey on mytable  (cost=0.61..653.66 rows=150 width=794)
   Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{...}'::bigint[]))
```